# Count all the grouped rows with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to count all the grouped rows but have no clue how to do it, if possible, with Eloquent.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT date FROM `reports` WHERE project_id = X GROUP BY `date`) as t1
```

As of now I'm using raw database queries:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM (SELECT date FROM `" . (new Report)->getTable() . "` WHERE project_id = " . ((int) $this->project->id) . " GROUP BY `date`) as t1"))[0]->total
```

Is it possible to achieve this with Eloquent, or at least make the PHP "call" prettier?

Comment: Adding `->count()` after groupBy might work, Have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries):

I'd do something along this (I don't think you need that subquery):

```
Report::where('project_id', $this->project->id)
    ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT date'));
```

Comment: Won't work. It doesn't count how many rows that have been returned from the `groupBy`.

Comment: Thanks mate. Way more cleaner.